# Unsupported attribute tabIndex on apex:inputField - doc contradictory

Tags: visualforce

No idea why I'm getting this error and it's avoiding me from saving my visualforce page in which all of my inputs are wrapped within the `apex:Form` Tag. `TabIndex(s)` are supported by salesforce as explained in this doc: [Setting the Tab Order for Fields in a form](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_input_field_tabindex.htm)

> The tabIndex attribute can be set on the following Visualforce components:

```
<apex:commandButton>
<apex:commandLink>
<apex:inputCheckbox>
<apex:inputField>
<apex:inputFile>
<apex:inputSecret>
<apex:inputText>
<apex:inputTextarea>
<apex:outputLabel>
<apex:outputLink>
<apex:selectCheckboxes>
<apex:selectList>
<apex:selectRadio>
```

Any suggestions?

Salesforce Browser Error:
[image: Inline Browser Edit]

Eclipse error:
[image: Salesforce Visualforce Page tabIndex Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is interesting that the doc says that.... because if you look at the API for the **apex:inputField** you see it isn't in there:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm

It's even more interesting that is what they use for all the samples.  I tried it myself and it doesn't work.  I would assume that it's not supported on apex:inputField though since it's not mentioned in that link I posted.

EDIT:  It is specifically mentioned on the other tags but not apex:inputField.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_inputField.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_inputField.htm|SkinName=webhelp

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref_inputField.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_compref_inputField.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Yeah, ended up using a mix of `tabIndex` for `inputTextFields`, `inputCheckbox`, and then using `tabOrderHint` for `inputField`. Weird thing though is that `tabOrderHint` is the specific number I mentioned, but `tabIndex` always had a multiple of 10... so if i had set it to 4 it was 40